# Testcafe Selector to identify element inside the specific component of DOM Structure

Tags: dom, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

How to convert the below Relative path to TestCafe Selector?

//a[contains(@name,'indent')]/parent::div//span[contains(text(),'Follow')]

If I try the above one, it recognizes specific DOM Component which contains multiple elements and one of those is 'Follow'.

how to achieve this using TestCafe Selectors.

I did not succeeded with the below one : 
Selector('a').withAttribute('@name','indent').parent('div').child('span').contains('Follow')

Selector('a').withAttribute('@name','indent').parent('div').child('span').withText('Follow')

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and found a couple of possible causes, which can lead to the issue.

1. [TestCafe Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/select-page-elements.html) do not have the `contains` method so the first example is incorrect.
2. Though I don't know your html structure, I can currently assume that there is no need to pass the `@` char in the attribute argument.

Thus your second example looks valid excepting the `@` char.

If this recommendation does not help, please provide us with a working example that shows the issue and create a separate bug report in the TestCafe repository using the following [form](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md)

Comment: sorry in delaying responding,  Yes, you are correct i should remove @ char. The element is not identifiable even after removing @ char. I am thinking do we have any other alternative to handle following :: *, Following-sibling, etc.

Comment: I think the best option is to prepare a sample project or url to your website which demonstrates the issue. It will help me to research the issue efficiently.
For now, it's quite difficult to determine the cause of the issue without an example.